# How do I access database context form view in .NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, code-injection

How do I access a database context form view in .NET Core to create a custom HTML helper extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use @inject key word.
@inject StatisticsService StatsService

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2